# Reading a String and get the numbers out of it;

Tags: java, string, equation

I want to parse numbers from a String.

Example input String: `0 = 2*x+2*x^2-4`

Transform to:

`leftside = 0`

`rightside = 2*x,2*x^2,-4`

Finally I want to save the numbers in variables like `leftN = 0` , `rightX = 2`

How can this be done? Any hints?

Comment: String splitting and number parsing.

Comment: To get the actual numbers you have to make an evaluator. Google for it

Comment: You can also refer to this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785553/how-does-a-simple-calculator-with-parentheses-work) or [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) for more information (note: totally advanced compared to your question).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Obtaining the polynomial degree for each side? Your question is vague.

Answer (score 2):

First you can split the string into two, LHS anf RHS by using method `split()`
method signature looks like this,

```
 public String[] split(String regex, int limit) //limit: maximum strings splited
```

or

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Simple example maybe,

```
String[] str_array = "0 = 2*x+2*x^2-4".split(" = ");
String LHS = str_array[0]; 
String RHS = str_array[1];
```

Further keep splitting the RHS string and get it as maybe `elements[]` by splitting with `-` and `+` so you can further divide and get the RHS as terms.

for getting numbers as `int`s you can use,

```
try{
   Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
   parsable = false;
}
```

Comment: @MarvinJoke it will be highly appreciated if you can accept my answer, if you found it useful!

Answer (score 0):

Split your string with the char you want it in to be different

```
String[] s = display.split("=");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to retrieve values of 0 and 2, you can use the `split()` method further to retrieve the exact values:

```
String display = "0 = 2*x+2*x^2-4";
int leftN = Integer.parseInt(display.split("=")[0].trim());
int rightX = Integer.parseInt(display.split("=")[1].trim().split("\\*")[0].trim());
System.out.println(leftN + ", " + rightX);
//output: 0, 2
```

The first line retrieves the first value from the split at `=`.
The second line retrieves the second value from the split at `=`, and then splits all cases of `*`. It retrieves the first value from that split. `trim()` is to ensure there are no white-spaces, which woud result in a `NumberFormatException`.

However, if you're not wanting the values to be of `int` value:

```
String display = "0 = 2*x+2*x^2-4";
String leftN = (display.split("=")[0].trim();
String rightX = display.split("=")[1].trim().split("\\*")[0].trim();
System.out.println(leftN + ", " + rightX);
//output: 0, 2
```

Further, if you're wanting to grab the `2` at the `x^2` portion of the equation:

```
String rightX = display.split("\\^")[1].trim().split("-")[0].trim();
```

Comment: it does not require them to be parsed to ints right? look at his example!

Comment: `save the numbers in variables like leftN = 0 , rightX = 2`. Maybe he doesn't, but at least it shows it grabs the values correctly.

Comment: Note that in the case of `"x^2"` this doesn't work. The `2` he wants, I'm assuming, is the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: @mbomb007 Seems like pure speculation, but just in case I threw it in the answer anyway.