# How does the sample grammar on the antlr4 home page work?

Tags: antlr4

Calculator math operator precedence is often remembered pneumonic PMDAS.

The grammar on the [ANTLR home page](http://www.antlr.org/) (using the same abbreviations) has order MDASP. This isn't PMDAS or reverse PMDAS like I would expect. E.g. [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786085/6659163) contains a grammar that looks like PMDAS.

But no matter what expressions I put into the command line; the parse tree looks correct!

```
grammar Expr;       
prog:   (expr NEWLINE)* ;
expr:   expr ('*'|'/') expr
    |   expr ('+'|'-') expr
    |   INT
    |   '(' expr ')'
    ;
NEWLINE : [\r\n]+ ;
INT     : [0-9]+ ;
```

How does this work?

Comment: What expressions did you try to parse?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little tricky to answer as im not entirely sure what you were trying to parse but pseudo code for what this grammar expects may help you understand it:

```
An int is one or more numbers from 0 to 9
A new line is one or more \r\n

an (expr)ession is made up of any of these:
an expression with a '*' or '/' and another expression
an expression with a '+' or '-' and another expression
an int
a curly brace containing an expression followed by a curly brace

the (prog)ram is made up of zero or more expressions followed by new lines.
```

Also remember that ANTLR:

> goes for the longest sequence first.  if two rules or more match the
>   longest possible sequence then it chooses the lexical rule specified
>   first

[This link](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=251) may be very useful to you. Anyway if you post the tree you are struggling to understand we could try and help you further. Good luck with your project.